# Bit shifting results in negative number

Tags: c, bit-shift

I'm working on an assignment that deals with compression and decompression. More specifically, a variation of run-length encoding (9-bit blocks). The issue I am having deals with the sign of the "type" bit. I am able to acquire the desired bit, however, in the cases that the bit should be a 1, my printf returns -1. This would lead me to believe that I am not doing something correct in my bit shifting, but I am unaware as to what that might be.

```
void bitShift(char * mostFreq, unsigned char * byteBuf, int byteCount) {
    char type;
    int typels = 0;
    int typers = 7;

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < byteCount - 1; i++) {
            type = byteBuf[i];
            printf("type before = %d\t", (unsigned int)type);
            type = type << typels;
            type = type >> typers;
            typels++;
            printf("type after = %d\n", (unsigned int)type);
    }/*End for i*/


    for(i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
            byteBuf[i] = 0;

}/*End bitShift*/

void decompressFile(char * mostFreq) {
    unsigned char byteBuf[9] = { 0 };
    int num, byteCount, i;
    num = 0; byteCount = 0; i = 0;
    unsigned char buf;
    while((num = read(0,&buf, 1)) > 0) {
            byteBuf[byteCount] = buf;
            byteCount++;
            if(byteCount == 9) {/*Flush bytes if buffer is full*/
                    bitShift(mostFreq, byteBuf, byteCount);
                    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                            byteBuf[i] = 0;
                    }/*End for i*/
                    byteCount = 0;
            }/*End if*/
    }/*End while*/
    if(num == 0) {/*If EOF*/
            if(byteCount != 0) {/*Bits have not been flushed*/
                    bitShift(mostFreq, byteBuf, byteCount);
            }/*End if*/
    } else if(num < 0) {
            perror("Read error");
            exit(1);
    }/*End else if*/

}/*End decompressFile*/
```

Comment: Why is `char type;` in `bitShift` instead of `unsigned char type;` as everywhere?

Comment: That was the issue. I somehow skipped over that one. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that you declared `type` as a plain `char` that, in your system seems to be a signed type.

So when you have for example `0x80`, it is actually `-128`, a negative number, and when it is shifted to the right the sign bit is extended: 1 bit: `0xC0 (-64)`, 2 bits: `0xE0 (-32)`, ... 7 bits: `0xFF (-1)`.

Change it to `unsigned char` and done!